# MVVM C# with the View on a remote Computer

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, client-server, remoting

I'm designing a Client/Server App in C# where all the Model Object and calculation has to be done on the server. The server doesn't need a specific UI.
Meanwhile I'd like my clients to be able to execute different functions or services from the server and receive the result of the computation from it as well as binding or subscribing to some values and each time the server update it, it sends the update to all clients who subscribed to this value.

Nothing spectacular in this I think.
I dont have any background in Network or Server-Client apps.

My question is the following:

I'd like to bind directly properties of my ViewModel which is Server side to the View which is Client Side.
Is there a way for me to do this like if the view was in a normal local MVVM framework?
I'd like to avoid having to create a specific language between the clients and the server and having then to handle the queue and priorities of clients messages.
If not, would you have some readings to recommend ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: can you use `WCF`? There you can just implement an interface and then you just call client side functions on server like it's on a server. From there - there's only one step to change a property and create a simple binding

Comment: Can you provide more information about what the client and server look like? Is this a web, desktop, or mobile application?

Comment: It is a desktop Application, server and clients are on the same LAN network.
I'll have a look into WCF, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't want your views to rely on a network connection to stay responsive, even if you solve the technical challenges of what you are proposing. Networking should be done in a way that can fail gracefully.

This is bad and you should not do it. That's my opinion.

Additionally, you really shouldn't be designing your own protocol for communication. You could use something like WCF or another framework that allows you to just call a remote function.

Comment: I here you. I will put a "transition layer" so my View are not totally dependent on the server.